# How can you name a tuple used as a function parameter in C#?

Tags: c#, tuples, namedtuple

I want to use a tuple as an input argument for my function.

```
public void Sync(IEnumerable<Tuple<string, double>> labels)
```

But I also want to give the string and double a name. But I can't get the syntax right. I am looking at all kinds of other blogs about named tuples, but no one seem to named their tuples in the functions. Is it even possible?

I would expect it to look like this.

```
public void Sync(IEnumerable<Tuple<string Text, double Score>> labels)
```

Comment: that would basically look like this: `public void Sync(IEnumerable<(string Text, double Score)> labels)`

Comment: @MongZhu: Thank you, I tried this and now it states that I am missing a reference to ValueTuple2, so I guess I could fix that.